# How to identify in the directory the file with higher numbering and save in a variable?

Tags: php, glob, scandir

I have in a folder named files sequentially

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I know `glob` or `scandir` can list the files in a directory, but how would it be possible to identify the most current file (numbering) to sequence and save the next files with correct numbering?

summarizing: how to identify with PHP the file with higher number and save this in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can get the newest file from the directory.
- Remove 'file' substring from the file name, to get the last file
  number
- Increment the number and do string operations to get your new filename.

Try the following:

```
// $directory_path is the directory you are scanning
// Scan directory in descending order
$files = scandir($directory_path, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$last_file = $files[0];

// extract the last file number
$last_file_no = (int)str_replace('file', '', $last_file);

// prepare the new file name
$new_file_no = $last_file_no + 1;
$new_file_name = 'file'. $new_file_no;
```

Comment: @Gislef happy to help :)